# Aquaterm: titles and axis labels getting cut off

Tags: image, octave, gnuplot

I'm using aquaterm 1.0.1 through octave and gnuplot - on my mac - to generate printable plots. When aquaterm generates my plots, it has a habit of cutting off or cropping all of the titles and axis labels.

Is there another imaging program that works with octave that won't have this problem? Or are there other fixes I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the plot results from aquaterm more than x11. I wrote an m-file script, which is really a kludge, to fix this problem so aquaterm is useable. It seems like the title and xlabel text strings are written one line too high and too low in the figure window. Note -this script doesn't change the ylabel. If the magnitude of the printed y-coordinate values are too large, it tends to move the ylabel off the left side of the page. Anyway here is my kludge, just run it after all figures are complete.

```
function fixAxes
%---------------------------------------
%// Kludge to fix scaling of all figures
%// until GNU or I can find real fix.
%// Octave3.2.3 computes the scaling wrong
%// for this mac, such that the title 
%// and xlabel are not displayed.
%---------------------------------------
s = get(0,'showhiddenhandles');
set(0,'showhiddenhandles','on');
newpos = [0.13 0.135 0.775 0.75];        %// default is [0.13 0.11 0.775 0.815]
figs = get(0,'children');
if (~isempty(figs))
    for k=1:length(figs)
        cax = get(figs(k),'currentaxes');
        pos = get(cax,'position');       
        if ~(pos(1) == newpos(1) && ... 
             pos(2) == newpos(2) && ...
             pos(3) == newpos(3) && ...
             pos(4) == newpos(4))
            set(cax,'position',newpos);    
            set(0,'currentfigure',figs(k));
            drawnow();
        endif
    endfor
endif
set(0,'showhiddenhandles',s);
%---------------------------------------
endfunction
%---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know why aquaterm cuts of parts of your plot, you can try using X11 terminal.  In Octave, you can say `setenv GNUTERM 'x11'` to do so.